# perl / embperl -- IPC::Open3

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl, embperl, ipcopen3

I have a sample program in 2 formats perl & embperl

The perl version works as a CGI but the embperl version does not work.

Any suggestions or pointers to solutions would be appreciated

OS: Linux version 2.6.35.6-48.fc14.i686.PAE (...) (gcc version 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Oct 22 15:27:53 UTC 2010

NOTE: I originally posted this question to perlmonks [[x]](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1086395) and the embperl mailing list [[x]](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/modperl/embperl/106070) but didn't get a solution.

**perl working script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use IPC::Open3;

print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

my $cmd = 'ls';

my $pid = open3(*HIS_IN, *HIS_OUT, *HIS_ERR, $cmd);
close(HIS_IN);  # give end of file to kid, or feed him
my @outlines = <HIS_OUT>;              # read till EOF
my @errlines = <HIS_ERR>;              # XXX: block potential if massive
print "STDOUT: ", @outlines, "\n";
print "STDERR: ", @errlines, "\n";

waitpid( $pid, 0 );
my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;

print "child_exit_status: $child_exit_status\n";
```

**embperl non-working script**

```
[-
  use warnings;
  use strict;
  use IPC::Open3;

  my $cmd = 'ls';

  my $pid = open3(*HIS_IN, *HIS_OUT, *HIS_ERR, $cmd);

  close(HIS_IN);  # give end of file to kid, or feed him

  my @outlines = <HIS_OUT>;              # read till EOF
  my @errlines = <HIS_ERR>;              # XXX: block potential if massive
  print OUT "STDOUT: ", @outlines, "\n";
  print OUT "STDERR: ", @errlines, "\n";

  waitpid( $pid, 0 );
  my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;

  print OUT "child_exit_status: $child_exit_status\n";
-]
```

**Here is the output I receive**

```
STDERR: ls: write error: Bad file descriptor

child_exit_status: 2
```

Comment: What's `fileno(STDOUT)` before `open3`? IIRC, `open3` expects it to be `2`.

Comment: Please explain more what you mean.  I don't have fileno(STDOUT) in my script.

Comment: What value is returned by `fileno(STDOUT)` just before `open3`?

Comment: If I put fileno(HIS_OUT) before open3.  It returns nothing for perl and 19 or 20 for embperl.

Comment: I asked for `fileno(STDOUT)`. While you're at it, what's `tied(STDOUT)?1:0`

Comment: embperl:  fileno is -1 and tied causes error "Error in Perl code: Can't modify constant item in tied".   perl: fileno is 1 and tied causes error "Can't modify constant item in tied"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open3` redirects the file descriptor associated with STDOUT, excepting it to be fd `1` (what the program you `exec` will consider STDOUT). But it's not `1`. It doesn't even have a file descriptor associated with it! I consider this a bug in `open3`. I think you can work around it as follows:

```
local *STDOUT;
open(STDOUT, '>&=', 1) or die $!;
...open3...
```

Comment: I added this before the call to open3 and received the following error "Error in Perl code: Bad file descriptor"

Comment: fd 1 is closed?!? yuck! You'll need to 1) open an arbitrary file handle (say `/dev/null`), 2) Use `POSIX::dup2` to copy that descriptor to descriptor 1 if it's not already 1. 3) Then you use the workaround I posted.

Comment: This is a bit over my head...  Can you provide or point me to an example for 1) & 2).

Comment: `open(my $fh, '>', '/dev/null') or die $!; dup2(fileno($fh), 1) or die $! if fileno($fh) != 1;`

Comment: This is awesome.  Can the same be used for STDIN? open(my $fh, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!; dup2(fileno($fh), 1) or die $! if fileno($fh) != 1; local *STDIN; open(STDIN, '<&=', 1) or die $!;

Comment: yeah, but fd `0`. Do STDIN before STDOUT.

Comment: I added the following before STDOUT.  It creates a **<defunct>** process. _Should I create another question for this?_:    `open($fhIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!; dup2(fileno($fhIN), 0) or die $! if fileno($fhIN) != 0; local *STDIN; open(STDIN, '<&=', 0) or die $!;`

Comment: You need to reap the process after it's ended. (e.g. `waitpid( $pid, 0 );`)

Comment: I made a separate follow up question for the STDIN with the complete code. [embperl - Using IPC::Open3 to call wkhtmltopdf. STDIN Not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838336/embperl-using-ipcopen3-to-call-wkhtmltopdf-stdin-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you sooo much to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)!!!!

Here is the embperl code that works.  P.S. There is a similar problem with STDIN.  I don't know the solution to that yet, but I think it is similar.

```
[-
  use warnings;
  use strict;
  use IPC::Open3;
  use POSIX;

  $http_headers_out{'Content-Type'} = "text/plain";

  my $cmd = 'ls';

  open(my $fh, '>', '/dev/null') or die $!; 

  dup2(fileno($fh), 1) or die $! if fileno($fh) != 1;

  local *STDOUT;
  open(STDOUT, '>&=', 1) or die $!;

  my $pid = open3(*HIS_IN, *HIS_OUT, *HIS_ERR, $cmd);

  close(HIS_IN);  # give end of file to kid, or feed him

  my @outlines = <HIS_OUT>;              # read till EOF
  my @errlines = <HIS_ERR>;              # XXX: block potential if massive
  print OUT "STDOUT: ", @outlines, "\n";
  print OUT "STDERR: ", @errlines, "\n";

  waitpid( $pid, 0 );
  my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;

  print OUT "child_exit_status: $child_exit_status\n";
-]
```