# embperl - Using IPC::Open3 to call wkhtmltopdf. STDIN Not working

Tags: perl, stdin, wkhtmltopdf, embperl, ipcopen3

From within embperl, I am trying to call wkhtmltopdf with the IPC::Open3 module.

I get output (thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) ) from wkhtmltopdf but no input is going to wkhtmltopdf.

This is related to this question: [perl / embperl — IPC::Open3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770338/perl-embperl-ipcopen3/23795617)

Here is the code:

```
[-
  use warnings;
  use strict;
  use IPC::Open3;
  use POSIX;
  use Symbol;

  my $cmd = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf - -';

  my $pdf = '';

  my $string = '<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       Hello World!!!
     </body>
     </html>';

  my $fhOUT = gensym();
  open($fhOUT, '>', '/dev/null') or die $!; 
  dup2(fileno($fhOUT), 1) or die $! if fileno($fhOUT) != 1;
  local *STDOUT;
  open(STDOUT, '>&=', 1) or die $!;

  my $pid = open3(*HIS_IN, *HIS_OUT, *HIS_ERR, $cmd)  or die "could not run cmd : $cmd : $!\n";

  print HIS_IN $string;
  close(HIS_IN);

  while( <HIS_OUT> ) {
    $pdf .= $_;
  }


  waitpid($pid, 0 ) or die "$!\n";
  my $retval =  $?;
  # print "retval-> $retval<br />\n";

  $http_headers_out{'Content-Type'}         = "application/pdf";
  $http_headers_out{'Content-Disposition'}  = "attachment; filename=pdfTest.pdf";

  $escmode = 0;
-]
[+ $pdf +]
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea for STDIN, but fd 0 instead of 1.

```
 open(my $fhIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
 dup2(fileno($fhIN), 0) or die $! if fileno($fhIN) != 0;
 local *STDIN; open(STDIN, '<&=', 0) or die $!;

 open(my $fhOUT, '>', '/dev/null') or die $!;
 dup2(fileno($fhOUT), 1) or die $! if fileno($fhOUT) != 1;
 local *STDOUT; open(STDOUT, '>&=', 1) or die $!;

 my $pid = open3(
    local *HIS_IN,
    local *HIS_OUT,
    '>&STDERR',
    $cmd
 );

 ...
```

This assumes fd 0 and 1 are closed, as is the case here.

Comment: Hello ikegami.  Thank you for taking the time to answer.   It seems to work but now there is a **defunct process** showing up in the process list. `apache   24480 24396  0 14:34 ?        00:00:00 [wkhtmltopdf] <defunct>`

Comment: A defunct process is one that hasn't bee reaped (e.g. using `wait` or `waitpid`).

Comment: I added the waitpid and it works when I add `open(my $fhIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
dup2(fileno($fhIN), 0) or die $! if fileno($fhIN) != 0;
local *STDIN; open(STDIN, '<&=', 0) or die $!;`   After that, I can't output anything to through html.  It writes to a file fine so I know it works but I can not write to the browser.

Comment: You have a system were the file handkes and file descriptors are severely messed up. Looks like we clobbered the file descriptor you're using for output, so you'll need to back it up.

Comment: How do I un-clobber the file descriptor/handle after it's done with the open3() part?

Comment: dup2 to a temp number, then dup2 back to the original number. Perhaps. This is getting very very complicated. Normally, you'd do this stuff post-fork.